# how to retrieve elements of the object after refreshing the application?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form

```
<input type="text" id='name'>
<input type="text" id='place'>
<button id='add'>Add</button>        
<button id='show'>Show</button>
```

I have a n object to collect the elements when Add button is triggered and the code is

```
var measure = {};
$("#add").click(function(){
    measurecol = new Object();
    measurecol.name = $("#name").val();
    measurecol.place = $("#place").val();
    measure[measurecol.name] = measurecol;
});
```

Whe I refresh my application, first it shows the elements of the object when no action is performed in the Add button:

```
{ 'foo': { 'name':'foo', 'place': 'foo1' } }
```

But when I fill the form and trigger Add button, the old element in the object gets deleted and the new one is added in the object. This happens only on refreshing the application.

So, my question is how to retrieve the element of the object upon refreshing the application and upon adding an element, it should add with the old one:

```
{
  'foo': {
    'name': 'foo',
    'place': 'foo1'
   },
   'goo': {
     'name': 'goo',
     'place': 'goo1'
   }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27273444/save-and-load-input-values-using-local-storage

Comment: no....mine is different. when reloading the application, i can get the old elements in object but when i trigger the add button, the new one is added by removing the old one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you can check whether the object is empty or not. If its empty, add the element in the object else if its not empty, append the element based on the length of the object.

```
if(measure != undefined && measure !={}){
    measure[measure.length] = measurecol;
}else{
    measure[measure.length+1] = measurecol;
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: you do realize that `measure != {}` will always return `true` because your comparing it to a fresh new empty object literal

Comment: First time it will be empty and when the element is added, the measure will  not be empty so the condition will be satisfied

Answer (score 1):

Whenever the click method is executed you are creating a new object

```
measurecol = new Object();
```

which deletes/replaces the previous object. So you loose your previously stored data.

if you don't use var before a variable name it creates a global variable. So you just have one measurecol variable which gets a new value everytime.
add this

```
var measurecol = new Object();
```

Answer (score 0):

use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

```
var measure = localStorage;
$("#add").click(function(){ 
    measurecol.name = $("#name").val();
    measurecol.place = $("#place").val();
    measure[measurecol.name] = measurecol;
});
```

i think it will work

Answer (score 0):

Using `localStorage`:

```
var measure = {};
$("#add").click(function(){
    measurecol = new Object();
    measurecol.name = $("#name").val();
    measurecol.place = $("#place").val();
    measure[measurecol.name] = measurecol;
    var lastobject =  localStorage.getItem("lastobj");

    if(lastobject){
        lastobject = JSON.parse(lastobject);
        var l = Object.keys(lastobject).length
        lastobject['obj'+l]=measurecol;
    }else{
        lastobject = new Object();
        lastobject.obj0 = measurecol;
    }
    localStorage.setItem("lastobj", JSON.stringify(lastobject));
});
```