# How to change language without losing data in dynamic form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a multi-tab dynamic form wizard. I pull form data (like textbox, radio etc..) from database using jQuery AJAX. I need to put language switch system in it but while user changing language, user input should not be remove and form should be in same tab. I am working on CodeIgniter. I am using PHP based  language switch technique in it but problem is when language changed, all data clear and it start from first tab. How to fix it?

Comment: Try to save all inputs in localstorage when language change is triggered.
Here's an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27273444/save-and-load-input-values-using-local-storage