# Can I keep fields in a form populated even if I move to a different page and then back?

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently looking at creating a form using HTML, CSS and a bit of JavaScript. I was wondering though if anyone had any ideas how I could keep all the fields populated?

I want to be able to fill in a form and click 'Next' which will go to a different page with a different form. But if the user presses the 'Back' button to edit some information on the previous page for example, how would I keep all the fields populates?

Bit stumped on this, so any suggestions would be appreciated :)

Comment: You can use session or cookie when you post and retrieve from there when you come back to the form. You can also use a temp table to store and retrieve.

Comment: @RahulKate I didn't think of using cookies, i'll look in to that! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You may use localStorage or cookies for that purpose to store content of the page on the client' side.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27273657/696034 for an example; in you case, you call save() when receiving location change event, and load() on the page' initialization.

Comment: Indeed. I too would recommend cookies for this - they are very east to use!

Comment: Thank you, i'll have a look at the cookies now!